# how should I optimise the scala code and make it more readable

Tags: scala

I have this ugly massive piece of code. It does many things, mostly around querying databases. Each query depends on the result of the previous query or on the parameters of the incoming request body. Queries are done asynchronously using `Future`. The code works but is not readable. How can I restructure it to make it concise? I have thought of using `for` instead of `map` and `flatMap` but due to dependencies on previous queries, I am not able to figure out how to use result of previous `Future` in new ones and how to handle error paths.

I am using `play 2.6` and `scala 2.12.2`

```
      def oldSignupUser:Action[AnyContent] = silhouette.UserAwareAction.async {
        implicit request => {

        val body: AnyContent = request.body
        val jsonBody: Option[JsValue] = body.asJson

        jsonBody match {
          case Some(json) => { 
            val userProfile: Option[UserProfile] = json.asOpt[UserProfile]             userProfile match {
              case Some(profile) => { 


                val loginInfo = LoginInfo(CredentialsProvider.ID, profile.externalProfileDetails.email)
                val userKeys = UserKeys(utilities.bucketIDFromEmail(profile.externalProfileDetails.email),profile.externalProfileDetails.email,loginInfo,profile.externalProfileDetails.firstName,profile.externalProfileDetails.lastName)
                val findUserFuture: Future[Option[User]] = userRepo.findOne(userKeys) // userFuture will eventually contain the result of database query i.e Some(user) or None

                findUserFuture.flatMap { (userOption: Option[User]) => 
                  userOption match {
                    case Some(user) => {
                      if(user.profile.internalProfileDetails.get.confirmed) {
                        Future {
                          Ok(Json.toJson(JsonResultError(messagesApi("error.duplicateUser")(langs.availables(0)))))
                        } 
                      } else { 
                        val userKeys = UserKeys(utilities.bucketIDFromEmail(user.profile.externalProfileDetails.email),user.profile.externalProfileDetails.email,loginInfo,user.profile.externalProfileDetails.firstName,user.profile.externalProfileDetails.lastName)
                        val userToken:UserToken = utilities.createUserToken(user.id,userKeys,UserTokenType.RegistrationConfirmation)
                        val userTokenSaveFuture:Future[Option[UserToken]] = userTokenRepo.save(userToken)
                        logger.trace(s"user token save future ${userTokenSaveFuture}")
                        userTokenSaveFuture.map( (userTokenOption:Option[UserToken])=>{
                          userTokenOption match {
                            case Some(userToken) => {
                              val signupEmailOption:Option[SignupEmail] = createEmailMessageForUserToken(userToken)
                              signupEmailOption match {
                                case Some(signupEmail:SignupEmail) =>{
                                  val _:String = mailerService.sendEmail(signupEmail.subject, signupEmail.from,List(user.profile.externalProfileDetails.email),None,Some(signupEmail.html))
                                  Ok(Json.toJson(JsonResultSuccess(messagesApi("success.userSignupConfirmationEmailSent")(langs.availables(0)))))
                                }
                                case None =>{
                                  InternalServerError(Json.toJson(JsonResultError("Internal Server Error")))
                                }
                              }
                            }
                            case None => {
                              Ok(Json.toJson(JsonResultError("user not added"))) //Todom - this is misleading as user is added but token isn't
                            }
                          }
                        })
                      }
                    }
                    case None => {
                      val passwordInfo:PasswordInfo = userRepo.hashPassword(profile.externalProfileDetails.password.get)
                      val bucketId = utilities.bucketIDFromEmail(profile.externalProfileDetails.email)
                      val newUser:User = User(
                        utilities.getUniqueID(),//UUID.randomUUID(),
                        UserProfile(Some(InternalUserProfile(loginInfo,bucketId,false,Some(passwordInfo))),
                          profile.externalProfileDetails))
                      val saveUserFuture:Future[Option[User]] = userRepo.save(newUser)

                      saveUserFuture.flatMap { (userOption:Option[User]) =>{                           userOption match {
                            case Some(user) => {
                              val initialPortfolio = user.profile.externalProfileDetails.portfolio
                              val profileAndPortfolio = profile.externalProfileDetails.copy(portfolio = initialPortfolio)
                              logger.trace(s"saving external profile and portfolio ${profileAndPortfolio}")
                              val savedProfileAndPortfolioOptionFuture = userProfileAndPortfolioRepo.save(profileAndPortfolio)
                              savedProfileAndPortfolioOptionFuture.flatMap(profileAndPortfolioOption =>{
                                profileAndPortfolioOption match {
                                  case Some(profileAndPortfolio) => {
                                    val userKeys = UserKeys(utilities.bucketIDFromEmail(user.profile.externalProfileDetails.email),user.profile.externalProfileDetails.email,loginInfo,user.profile.externalProfileDetails.firstName,user.profile.externalProfileDetails.lastName)
                                    val userToken:UserToken = utilities.createUserToken(user.id,userKeys,UserTokenType.RegistrationConfirmation)
                                    val userTokenSaveFuture:Future[Option[UserToken]] = userTokenRepo.save(userToken)

                                    userTokenSaveFuture.flatMap( (userTokenOption:Option[UserToken])=>{
                                      userTokenOption match {
                                        case Some(userToken) => {
                                          val signupEmailOption = createEmailMessageForUserToken(userToken)
                                          signupEmailOption match {
                                            case Some(signupEmail) =>{
                                              val _:String = mailerService.sendEmail(signupEmail.subject,signupEmail.from,List(user.profile.externalProfileDetails.email),None,Some(signupEmail.html))
Future{Ok(Json.toJson(JsonResultSuccess((messagesApi("success.userSignupConfirmationEmailSent"))(langs.availables(0)))))}
                                            }
                                            case None =>{
                                              Future{InternalServerError(Json.toJson(JsonResultError("Internal Server Error")))}
                                            }
                                          }
                                        }
                                        case None => {
                                          Future{Ok(Json.toJson(JsonResultError("user not added"))) }
                                        }
                                      }
                                    })
                                  }
                                  case None =>{
                                    Future{InternalServerError(Json.toJson(JsonResultError("Internal Server Error")))}
                                  }
                                }
                              })
                            }
                            case None => {
                               Future{Ok(Json.toJson(JsonResultError("unable to add user")))}
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                        .recover { case x => {
                          x match {
                            case _:EmailException =>InternalServerError(Json.toJson(JsonResultError("The server encountered internal error and couldn't sent email to the email id.")))
                            case _ => InternalServerError(Json.toJson(JsonResultError("Internal Server Error")))
                          }
                        }
                      }

                    }
                  }
                }
                .recover { case x => {
                    logger.trace("Future failed in signupUser. In recover. Returning Internal Server Error"+x)
                    x match {
                      case _:EmailException =>InternalServerError(Json.toJson(JsonResultError("The server encountered internal error and couldn't sent email to the email id.")))
                      case _ => InternalServerError(Json.toJson(JsonResultError("Internal Server Error")))
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
              case None => Future {
                logger.trace("invalid profile structure")

                Ok(Json.toJson(JsonResultError(messagesApi("error.incorrectBodyStructure")(langs.availables(0)))))  } 
            }
          }
          case None => Future {
            Ok(Json.toJson(JsonResultError(messagesApi("error.incorrectBodyType")(langs.availables(0))))) }

          }
        }
      }
```

Update - the question was closed before I could solve the problem. Many thanks to mfirry and tim for their answers. this is the version I could come up with which I believe is modular.

```
  def getUserProfileFromBody(json:JsValue): Option[UserProfile] ={
    val userProfile = json.asOpt[UserProfile] //check if json conforms with UserProfile structure
    userProfile
  }

  def getJsonBody(body:AnyContent) = {
    val jsonBody: Option[JsValue] = body.asJson
    jsonBody
  }

  def generateUserKeysFromUserProfile(profile:UserProfile):UserKeys = {
    val loginInfo = LoginInfo(/*provider id eg "credentials"*/CredentialsProvider.ID, /*provider Key eg email*/profile.externalProfileDetails.email)
    val userKeys = UserKeys(utilities.bucketIDFromEmail(profile.externalProfileDetails.email),profile.externalProfileDetails.email,loginInfo,profile.externalProfileDetails.firstName,profile.externalProfileDetails.lastName)
    logger.trace(s"generated userkey ${userKeys}")
    userKeys

  }

  def findIfUserIsNewOrExisting(userKey:UserKeys): Future[Boolean] ={
    logger.trace(s"looking for user with keys ${userKey}")
    val findUserFuture  = userRepo.findOne(userKey) // userFuture will eventually contain the result of database query i.e Some(user) or None
    logger.trace(s"user future is ${findUserFuture}")
    for(userOption <- findUserFuture) yield {
      logger.trace(s"user option ${userOption}")
      userOption match {
        case Some(user) => {
          val userConfirmed = isUserConfirmed(user)
          if(userConfirmed) {
             throw new DuplicateUserException(user,"duplicateuser", new Throwable("duplicateuser"))
          } else throw new UnconfirmedUserException(user,"unconfirmeduser", new Throwable("unconfirmeduser"))
        }
        case None => {
          false
        }
      }
    }
  }



  def returnError(error:String) = {
    println(s"returning error ${error}")
    Future {
      /*
      note the distintion between langs and messages. Lang means languages this application supports
      eg English, French
      Messages are the messages defined per language. Eg app.title is a message defined inn English. It might not be defined in French
       */

      /*logger.trace("langs array"+langs.availables) //languages available
      logger.trace("app.title: "+messagesApi.isDefinedAt("app.title")(langs.availables(0)))//pick the first language and see taht app.title is defined in it
      logger.trace("error: "+messagesApi.isDefinedAt("error.incorrectBodyType")(langs.availables(0)))//see taht error.incorrectBodyType is defined in the 1st language
      */
      Ok(Json.toJson(JsonResultError(error)))
    }/*TODOM - Standardise error messages. Use as constants*/
  }

  def isUserConfirmed(user:User):Boolean = user.profile.internalProfileDetails.get.confirmed

  def sendConfirmationTokenForUser(user:User) = {
    val userKeys = generateUserKeysFromUserProfile(user.profile)
    //for this user, create a token which could be sent in the email for verification
    val userToken:UserToken = utilities.createUserToken(user.id,userKeys,UserTokenType.RegistrationConfirmation)
    logger.trace(s"saving token ${userToken}")
    val userTokenSaveFuture:Future[Option[UserToken]] = userTokenRepo.save(userToken)
    logger.trace(s"user token save future ${userTokenSaveFuture}")

    for(userTokenOption <- userTokenSaveFuture) yield {
      logger.trace(s"user token ${userTokenOption}")
      userTokenOption match {
        case Some(userToken) => {
          val signupEmailOption:Option[SignupEmail] = createEmailMessageForUserToken(userToken)
          signupEmailOption match {
            case Some(signupEmail:SignupEmail) =>{
              val email = mailerService.sendEmail(signupEmail.subject, signupEmail.from,List(user.profile.externalProfileDetails.email),None,Some(signupEmail.html))
              println(s"sent email message ${email}")
              email
              //Ok(Json.toJson(JsonResultSuccess(messagesApi("success.userSignupConfirmationEmailSent")(langs.availables(0)))))
            }
            case None =>{
              logger.trace("unable to create html response for email confirmation")
              //InternalServerError(Json.toJson(JsonResultError("Internal Server Error")))
              throw EmailMessageCreationException("errorInCreatingHTML", new Throwable("errorInCreatingHTML"))
            }
          }
        }
        case None => {
          logger.trace("error in adding token")
          throw EmailTokenSaveException("emailTokenSaveException", new Throwable("emailTokenSaveException"))

          //Ok(Json.toJson(JsonResultError("user not added"))) //Todom - this is misleading as user is added but token isn't
        }
      }
    }
  }

  def addUserToDatabase(user:User) = {
    println(s"saving user ${user}")
    val saveUserFuture:Future[Option[User]] = userRepo.save(user)
    for(userOption <- saveUserFuture) yield {
      userOption match {
        case Some(user) => {
          logger.trace("user added successfully "+user)
          user
        }
        case None => throw new NewUserAdditionException("newUserAdditionError", new Throwable("newUserAdditionError"))
      }
    }
  }

  def addNewUser(profile:UserProfile) = {
    logger.trace(s"new user sign up request with profile ${profile}")
    ////NOTE - //salt is empty for BCryptSha256PasswordHasher. The 'hash' method of BCryptSha256PasswordHasher does not return the salt separately because it is embedded in the hashed password.
    //should creation of passwordInfo be moved to UserRepo? Not sure.
    //A profile associated with the credentials provider stores a Silhouette PasswordInfo object holding the hashed password
    //val passwordInfo:PasswordInfo = userRepo.passwordHasher.hash(profile.externalProfileDetails.password.get)
    val passwordInfo: PasswordInfo = userRepo.hashPassword(profile.externalProfileDetails.password.get)
    //logger.trace("password info is ",passwordInfo)
    val bucketId = utilities.bucketIDFromEmail(profile.externalProfileDetails.email)
    val loginInfo = LoginInfo(/*provider id eg "credentials"*/ CredentialsProvider.ID, /*provider Key eg email*/ profile.externalProfileDetails.email)
    val newUser: User = User(
      utilities.getUniqueID(), //UUID.randomUUID(),
      UserProfile(Some(InternalUserProfile(loginInfo, bucketId, false, Some(passwordInfo))),
        profile.externalProfileDetails))
    logger.trace("adding new user" + newUser)
    addUserToDatabase(newUser)
  }

  def saveProfileAndPortfolio(profileAndPortfolio:ExternalUserProfile) = {
    logger.trace(s"saving external profile and portfolio ${profileAndPortfolio}")
    val savedProfileAndPortfolioOptionFuture = userProfileAndPortfolioRepo.save(profileAndPortfolio)
    for(savedProfileAndPortfolio <- savedProfileAndPortfolioOptionFuture) yield {
      savedProfileAndPortfolio match {
        case Some(profileAndPortfolio) => profileAndPortfolio
        case None => throw ProfileAndPortfolioAdditionException("profileAndPortfolioAdditionException",new Throwable("profileAndPortfolioAdditionException"))
      }
    }
  }

  def createUserProfileAndPortfolioInformation(user:User) = {
    val profile = user.profile
    val initialPortfolio = user.profile.externalProfileDetails.portfolio //Some(TagsOfInterestToAUserAPI(Set(),Set(),Set()))
    val profileAndPortfolio = profile.externalProfileDetails.copy(portfolio = initialPortfolio)
    saveProfileAndPortfolio(profileAndPortfolio)
  }

  def signupUser = silhouette.UserAwareAction.async {
    implicit request => {
      logger.trace(s"received request ${request}")
      val jsonBody = getJsonBody(request.body)
      /*
      TODOM - testcase - check what happens if some other body type is sent.
       */
      jsonBody match {
        case Some(json) => { //got json in message body.
          //TODOM - convert to pretty print only if logger level is trace
          val readableString: String = Json.prettyPrint(json)
          logger.trace(s"received Json ${readableString}")
          val userProfile = getUserProfileFromBody(json)
          userProfile match {
            case Some(profile) => { //json conforms to UserProfile.
              logger.trace(s"received correct profile structure ${profile}")
              val userKeys = generateUserKeysFromUserProfile(profile)
              val res = for{isNewUser <- findIfUserIsNewOrExisting(userKeys) //this will throw error if user is duplicate
                            newUserDetails <- addNewUser(profile)
                            profileAndPortfolioInfo <- createUserProfileAndPortfolioInformation(newUserDetails)
                            confirmationEmail <- sendConfirmationTokenForUser(newUserDetails)} yield {
                Ok(Json.toJson(JsonResultSuccess((messagesApi("success.userSignupConfirmationEmailSent"))(langs.availables(0)))))
              }

              res.recover {
                case exception: DuplicateUserException => Ok(Json.toJson(JsonResultError(messagesApi("error.duplicateUser")(langs.availables(0)))))
                case exception: UnconfirmedUserException => {
                  sendConfirmationTokenForUser(exception.user)
                  Ok(Json.toJson(JsonResultSuccess((messagesApi("success.userSignupConfirmationEmailSent"))(langs.availables(0)))))
                }
                case _:EmailException =>InternalServerError(Json.toJson(JsonResultError("The server encountered internal error and couldn't sent email to the email id.")))
                case exception:ProfileAndPortfolioAdditionException => Ok(Json.toJson(JsonResultError("user not added")))
                case _:EmailMessageCreationException => Ok(Json.toJson(JsonResultError("user not added")))
                case _: EmailTokenSaveException=> Ok(Json.toJson(JsonResultError("user not added")))
                case x => {
                  logger.error(s"unknown exception ${x}")
                  InternalServerError(Json.toJson(JsonResultError("Internal Server Error")))
                }
              }
              res
            }
            //Json doesn't conform to UserProfile
            case None => Future {
              logger.trace("invalid profile structure")
              Ok(Json.toJson(JsonResultError(messagesApi("error.incorrectBodyStructure")(langs.availables(0)))))  } /*TODOM - Standardise error messages. Use as constants*/
          }
        }
        //message body is not json. Error.
        //TODOM - langs contains array of lang. picking the 1st one but would need too pick based on locale.
        //langs.availables(0) maps to array defined in application.conf eg. - play.i18n.langs = [ "en", "en-US", "fr" ]
        case None =>{
          logger.trace("incorrect body type")
          returnError(messagesApi("error.incorrectBodyType")(langs.availables(0)))
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Sounds like a post for stack code review...

Comment: can you post this again without the comments and the `logger.trace` parts?

Comment: removed comments and trace. thanks

Comment: Great. Also please add type signature to the `oldSignupUser` function.

Comment: Also, what version of Scala and what the main dependencies here. I guess it's Play.

Comment: done. Thanks for giving this your time

Comment: Is this inside some controllers? Very hard to make it compile. I think we need more details. Also, it seems to be using silhouette. I think it's best if you can if you share your build.sbt and plugins.sbt

Comment: done. Yes, it is inside a controller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210722/discussion-between-mfirry-and-manu-chadha).

Comment: thanks @mfirry. Your tips were helpful to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most obvious change is to **put code in functions**. By breaking up the logic into functions with meaningful names you make the code much clearer to read. If you define them as local functions within the method they can access context from the method without it having to be passed in as parameters.

Put all the error returns in static `val`s outside the method rather than creating them each time.

Consider using `Option.fold` rather than `match`:

```
option.fold(error){ result =>
  // Further code
}
```

Remove the `{}` after `case x =>`, they are not required.

The first `case` in `case x => { x match {` is redundant.

And don't worry about performance until you can prove that the performance of this section of code has a material effect on the behaviour of the application.

---

One problem is that you are not using the `Failure` case of `Future` to indicate failure so you can't use `map`/`flatMap` to chain operations that might fail.

Create your own subclass of `Exception` and have the methods return `Future.failed(MyException(error))` on failure rather than `Future(error)`

Then do this

```
val res = 
  for {
    res1 <- futureAction1
    res2 <- futureAction2(res1)
    res3 <- futureAction3(res2)
  } yield {
    res3
  }
```

and finally

```
res.recover{ case MyException(err) => err }
```

The `for` will stop at the first `Failure` return value, and the `recover` will turn this into the appropriate `Success` value.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I tried breaking logic into function. I can do that for some bits easily but for the ones which query a database (eg `users.findone()` which returns a `Future`, I feel the code starts getting messier w.r.t nesting. I suppose my main issue is that the code is nesting.

Comment: I've added an explanation of how to avoid nesting by using `Future` to track failure better.